# What is the proper way to forward declare a pointer to a class for use inside the class declaration?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

For example,

```
   class Segment
   {
      friend bool someFunc( P_Segment p );
   };

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Segment> P_Segment;
```

How best to declare P_Segment so this compiles?

Comment: Thanks all, I just wanted to make sure the not so elegant looking gyrations were necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have no choice since you can't forward declare typedefs. You'll have to forward declared the `Segment` class instead.

```
class Segment;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Segment> P_Segment;

class Segment
{
    friend bool someFunc( P_Segment p );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with what the others have said, but just for an alternative:

```
class Segment
{
public:
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<Segment> P_Segment;
   friend bool someFunc( P_Segment p );
};

using Segment::P_Segment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward declare your class, and after that forward declare smart pointer (shared_ptr can accepts incomplete types):

```
   class Segment;
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<Segment> Segment_PTR;

   class Segment
   {
      friend bool someFunc(Segment_PTR p);
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to make the typedef a member of the class:

```
class Segment
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Segment> pointer;
    friend bool someFunc( pointer p );
};
```

This changes how you access it of course, you noe have to use `Segment::pointer` outside of the class.